# Python software or libraries for solving job scheduling problem

Tags: python, scheduling, optimization, job-scheduler

I have a scheduling scenario in which every time period has a cost. I need to select the time periods which will give me the least cost over a period of 24 hours. See below for an example of the dataset.

### Start time | End time | Cost

- 00:00 | 01:00 | $30
- 01:00 | 05:00 | $50
- 02:00 | 08:00 | $70
- 04:00 | 12:00 | $100
- 08:00 | 11:00 | $60
- 10:00 | 14:00 | $50
- 13:00 | 17:00 | $90
- 13:00 | 20:00 | $120
- 16:00 | 23:00 | $80
- 18:00 | 22:00 | $60
- 19:00 | 20:00 | $50
- 21:00 | 23:00 | $20

Is there any Python software or library which I can use to derive the set of time periods which gives the least cost, each time period must not overlap and they must all add up to 24 hours?

Comment: The example has no solution. The first choice has to be option 1, the second choice has to be option 2, and there's no option that starts when option 2 begins.

Comment: Do they have to add up to 24 hours, or do they have to collectively cover a single unbroken 24-hour period?

Comment: They have to collectively cover a single unbroken 24-hour period. Gaps are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a knapsack problem variant.

I'd expect that [OptaPy](https://www.optapy.org) is able to handle it.